# Pygame won't detect a list in the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

First of all, I am aware some questions were asked similar to this but they didn't help me out.

I am trying to call a list in the same class but in a different method, it should work but it somehow doesn't.

The error:

```
'Player' object has no attribute 'standing_frames'
```

Where the list is defined:

```
self.standing_frames = [self.game.spriteheet.get_images(0, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(19, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(38, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(57, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(76, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(95, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(114, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(133, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(152, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(171, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(190, 0, 19, 34),
                            self.game.spriteheet.get_images(209, 0, 19, 34)]
```

Where the list is first called and where the error first come up:

```
        self.image = self.standing_frames[0]
```

All the pieces are in different methods but in the same class.
The spritesheet is a method where it separates a picture by the co-ordinates and the width and height, the image is already defined.

mcve and full code - [Github](https://github.com/Tudor0404/Stackoverflow-help-2-/tree/master)

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: But you haven't shown the actual class object... `self.standing_frames = [...]` doesn't tell us much on its own.

Comment: We need an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @skrx I will post on github, the link will be in a comment later on

Comment: @TudorPopescu no, post it here. Either make the question self-contained as much as possible or don't bother. I don't get the obsession with posting things offsite, there's no need. Any link might expire leaving the question nonsensical.

Comment: I guess list is not declared inside the  __init__  method. But question is not complete.

Comment: You have to create a minimal example and post it here, as others wrote. Anyway, here is a wild guess without the example: the second code (which has the error) was called, but the first one was not.

Comment: i have edited the question to add the mcve and the full code

Comment: I know you posted a link to a whole repository with the code and I appreciate that but I agree with posting all the relevant code here rather than just link to it, so for the sake of having this info clearly visible in the question: Does `self.standing_frames` appear in the code for the first time after or before `self.image = self.standing_frames[0]`?

Comment: @FrancoPino well they don't go after or before as it gets drawn at the same time and normally when I play around with pygame the order in classes doesn't really matter.

Comment: I'm not talking about the visuals of the program's execution, I'm asking for the literal code: I'm assuming the issue is that you wrote that `self.image = self.standing_frames[0]` before you had written the definition of `self.standing_frames`, so it crashes because the program doesn't know what is `self.standing_frames` when you try to use it for the self.image assignment (also this is not an order of classes issue, since it's within the same class?)

Comment: @FrancoPino Yes, I wrote self.image = self.standing_frames[0] before I defined it as that is where it has to be(in the init part), you can't move that part around as you have to initiate the sprite. And yes, it is not an order, as like you said again it is within the same class(except for the spritesheet method, which is written before it anyway)

Comment: @skrx I have finished the mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `self.load_images()` in the `Player` class, so the `self.standing_frames` attribute never gets assigned and the game crashes when you reference it the first time.

```
self.load_images()  # Call this before you use the `self.standing_frames` attribute.
self.image = self.standing_frames[0]
```

---

You also have to define a `self.spritesheet` attribute in the `Game` class.

```
self.spritesheet = Spritesheet('idle.png')  # Pass the filename.
```

Change the `__init__` method of the `Spritesheet` like so if you want to create different sheets:

```
class Spritesheet:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.spritesheet = pg.image.load(os.path.join(animation_folder, filename)).convert()
```

The `get_image` method could be beautified a bit with [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface).

It would also be possible to create all subsurfaces at the time of the instantiation, then you don't have to create a new surface every time an image is switched.

---

And there are two typos: `spriteheet` instead of `spritesheet` and `.get_images` instead of `.get_image`.

Comment: thanks alot, this obstacle has blocked me from progressing, thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome! It also looks like the animation code doesn't work as expected, but better try to fix it on your own first.

Comment: just a quick question, where would I define which file I want to use for the sprite_sheet class so I can use it more times in the load_images method? Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do. If you want to load several image files, just create new instances of the `Spritesheet` and pass the different file names, e.g. `self.spritesheet_idle = Spritesheet('idle.png')`, `self.spritesheet_walk = Spritesheet('walk.png')`.

Comment: Actually, the `Spritesheet` class isn't necessary here at all, because you're just appending the single images to lists. You could replace it with a simple function or a list comprehension as well.